# Cannot Find Element in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, element

I am trying to locate a dropdown menu button from the following website:

[Inspect Element snippet of 'CRO Dashboard DropDown Menu'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OSru.png)

My aim is to locate the dropdown button element and click it to open the menu to then continue other operations on it.

The following error occurs when trying to locate the dropdown menu button by id:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#dashboardSelectorLink"}

Referring to the image, from the highlighted part I tried to use various locators like finding element by **id**, **css selector**, **class names**, and even **xpath** but still the program could not locate it so that I can click the element.

Here is some of the code I tried:

```
dropdown = FindElementByCSS(dropdown, ".ms-crm-ImageStrip-Dropdown_Arrow");
dropdown = FindElementByXPath(dropdown, "//a[@id='dashboardSelectorLink']/span[2]/img");
dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[id=\"dashboardSelectorLink\"]"));
dropdown = FindElementByID(dropdown, "dashboardSelectorLink");
dropdown = FindElementByXPath(dropdown, "//cssclass[@id='dashboardSelectorLink']");
dropdown = FindElementByCSS(dropdown, "cssclass[id = 'dashboardSelectorLink']");
dropdown = FindElementByID(dropdown, "dashboardSelectorLink");
dropdown = FindElementByClass(dropdown, "cssclass[id= 'dashboardSelectorLink']");
dropdown = FindElementByID(dropdown, "dashboardSelectorContainer");
```

The variable 'dropdown' is of **IWebElement** type and I am using a **chrome driver** for Selenium C#.

For context, the code is in the following function:

```
public void EnterDashboardArea()
        {

            IWebElement navbtn = null;
            IWebElement category = null;
            IWebElement dropdown = null;


            navbtn = FindElementByID(navbtn, "Tab1");
            ClickElement(navbtn);

            category = FindElementByID(category, "MNG");
            ClickElement(category);

            Thread.Sleep(5000); //pausing the program so the page fully loads and all elements appear

            dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("img[class='ms-crm-ImageStrip-Dropdown_Arrow']"));
            ClickElement(dropdown);

        }
```

In the function **EnterDashboardArea()**, the web elements initially are set to **none** where they are then filled by the functions 'FindElementByX' as they return an element value.

The functions 'FindElementByX' are created by myself, one e.g. is:

```
public IWebElement FindElementByID(IWebElement ele, string id) {
            ele = driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));
            return ele;
        }
```

I even tried installing the selenium chrome extension in order to locate the target exactly but still no success.

What can I do please? - Thanks

Comment: Good morning- could you please elaborate on which element (including selector) is stored within the `dropdown` variable before you call `FindElementWithX(dropdown, ...)`

Comment: Hi, I updated my post to answer your question. As a note, I first avoided using the null values and just initialised the IWebElements when locating the element, but still the same error occurred of not finding the specific dropdown element.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are trying to retrieve the element before the element has been loaded into the DOM? Try to set a timeout before reading the element.

Also: is the element contained within a container that is initially hidden, before you open it? Maybe you have to click some button that shows the container and the target element within, before trying to read the element.

Comment: Regarding your first question, I thought about that and thats why I added 'Thread.Sleep()' before locating the element. It is inside the 'EnterDashboardArea()' function I posted.

Regarding your second question, I checked and the element is wrapped around an 'overflow: hidden' style tag which I don't think it relates to this but I'm pointing it out. I am not sure if it has to anything to do with it being hidden.

Comment: @gvella29 `overflow: hidden` means that it will hide the element if it's outside the container, but I don't think it affects the element DOM-wise.

Comment: @gvella29 Does it work with other elements? Try reading the entire page and then printing out the results and then try finding your target element in the printed results.

Comment: Yes I tried several other elements including the ones in the function 'EnterDashboardArea()' and they all are located successfully. This is the only element which gives me a problem. I will try to do that thnku.

Comment: @gvella29 another thing you can try - try to locate the parent element, if it doesn't get located, try locating the parent of *that* element, etc. Then you can identify the problematic element that doesn't get found

Comment: Last thing to be sure I am typing it correctly, this html part: 

`<a cssclass="ms-crm-View-Name" class="ms-crm-View-Name" id="dashboardSelectorLink" width="100%" onclick="return false;" title="Select Dashboard" href="javascript:void(0);">`

As a css selector should it be written like this: FindElementByCSS(dropdown, 'a[cssclass=ms-crm-View-Name]'); or different?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).